# what is the difference between INCLUDE 'param.inc' and INCLUDE 'param.fi'?

Tags: fortran, fortran77

How to make a file for .inc for extension in PGI visual FORTRAN?What is the difference between INCLUDE 'param.inc' and INCLUDE 'param.fi' ?

Answer (score 1):

The `INCLUDE` statement just includes any text file as a part of the source code.

The difference between your two statements is that one includes a file with a different file name than the other. The extension is completely irrelevant.

You can place in the file `param.whatever` any Fortran statements you need. Do not care about the file name.